# Initialize an array of Strings inside an enum

Tags: java, enums

I have an Enum in Java and each of its enumeration members have a number of parameters. What I am trying to do is make one of these parameters as an array of Strings but I can't seem to be able to make the correct initialization.

Here's what I've tried:

```
private static enum DialogType {
    ACCCAT("Acccat", new String[] {"acccatid"}, "acccatText", "dlg7Matchcode", "Zutritts\nkategorie", "Text"),

    private String mDialogName;
    private String[] mKeyField;
    private String mTextField;
    private String mSelectFields;
    private String mKeyFieldHeader;
    private String mTextFieldHeader;

    private DialogType(String dialogName, String[] keyField, String textField, String selectFields, String keyFieldHeader, String textFieldHeader) {
        mDialogName = dialogName;
        mKeyField = keyField;
        mTextField = textField;
        mSelectFields = selectFields;
        mKeyFieldHeader = keyFieldHeader;
        mTextFieldHeader = textFieldHeader;
    }
}
```

However, I am getting a ton of syntactic errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make that

```
public  enum DialogType {
    ACCCAT("Acccat", new String[] {"acccatid"}, "acccatText", 
           "dlg7Matchcode", "Zutritts\nkategorie", "Text");
```

And it should work. Note the `;` at the end of the ACCAT.
Also the enum can't be static.

Comment: Ah, stupid me, problem wasn't even related to my array. And my enum is internal to a JUnit test class so I don't think static is a problem. Although it might not make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick - Semicolon at the end of the ACCCAT line

```
private static enum DialogType {

    ACCCAT("Acccat", new String[]{"acccatid"}, "acccatText", "dlg7Matchcode", "Zutritts\nkategorie", "Text");
    private String mDialogName;
    private String[] mKeyField;
    private String mTextField;
    private String mSelectFields;
    private String mKeyFieldHeader;
    private String mTextFieldHeader;

    private DialogType(String dialogName, String[] keyField, String textField, String selectFields, String keyFieldHeader, String textFieldHeader) {
        mDialogName = dialogName;
        mKeyField = keyField;
        mTextField = textField;
        mSelectFields = selectFields;
        mKeyFieldHeader = keyFieldHeader;
        mTextFieldHeader = textFieldHeader;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ACCCAT("Acccat", new String[] {"acccatid"}, "acccatText", "dlg7Matchcode", "Zutritts\nkategorie", "Text");
```

I think you just want a semi-colon at the end of the instance declaration.

I presume the enum is static because it's an inner enum of something?